# LEDs flash briefly, but don't stay on

Tags: led, rgb, 5v

I've soldered a DC power pigtail to a string of 5V LED lights. When I connect the pigtail to the appropriate power source all of the lights flash very brightly and briefly just as the male end goes into the female, but then turn off once the male end has gone the slightest bit further into the female.

I've tried holding the male at the very tip of the female opening, but even then the LEDs only flash. I can't find the sweet spot where the LEDs stay on. Probably for the best, as I suspect I'm doing something wrong and that's causing the LEDs to behave this way. I can't figure out what, though, because I successfully turned on a Raspberry Pi using the same pigtail and power adapter, and didn't experience any of the problems that I have with these LEDs.

The pigtail I'm using strangely has the red and black swapped - that is, the red wire is negative and the black is positive.

These are the lights I'm using:
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00B4UKG2W/ref=oh_details_o09_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B4UKG2W)

They're individually addressable RGB, and the DI wire is not connected. I'm just connecting without the DI. Surely the DI doesn't need to be connected? There are five wires to connect: Two positive, two negative, and the fifth the DI. Presumably this is so one can connect without using the DI at all.

I'm very much a beginner at circuitry, but I really want to get this project working. I'm excitedly learning. I've searched, but haven't been able to find anyone else experiencing this problem, much less a solution.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this has to do with electronic design. What voltage is this "DC power pigtail"? The string needs 5 Volts, not 12. In the meanwhile, yes, the data input line most likely needs data, see the WS2811 datasheet. Voting to close.

Comment: I apologize if this was in the wrong place. Being a beginner, I may have misunderstood the guidelines. What would be the correct place to ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [controller chip datasheet](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf) isn't entirely clear, except for the mention of "Built-in electric reset circuit and power lost reset circuit", but it looks like it's designed to turn off the LEDs after power-up until it receives valid data.

You need to hook this kind of string up to a controller that sends serial data on the DI line to turn on each LED — actually, three color levels for each LED.

The behavior you're seeing with no DI connection is perfectly normal.

If you want a string of lights that just comes on when power is applied, then you need to get one that doesn't have the "individually addressable" feature.

Comment: I'll have time later today to test this. I wonder then, why does the light have two positive and two negative wires if you have to use the DI anyway? Are the extra two just for testing?

Comment: Probably just to handle the peak current. 50 RGB LEDs is going to add up to several amps total.